# Comparison signs (less than, less than or equal to, etc.)

Tags: ruby

I'm wondering how to test if a variable is between two values such as 1 and 10. For example I have the following:

```
bullet_hit = rand(1..10)
if 1 < bullet_hit < 10
  ...
```

I think I have the wrong syntax. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is actually a Ruby question, not erb specific. The syntax is valid but doesn't do what you want because `<` is a binary operator. `1 < bullet_hit` evaluates to a Boolean therefore the second `<` is comparing this Boolean instead of `bullet_hit` with `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as simplest syntax:

```
<% bullet_hit = rand(1..10) %>
<% if 1 < bullet_hit && bullet_hit < 10 %>
  <%= bullet_hit %>
<% end %>
```

but you have many methods to do it such as:

```
bullet_hit.between?(1,10) # true

(1..10).member?(bullet_hit) # true

(1..10).include?(bullet_hit)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Range#cover? method:

```
(2..9).cover?(bullet_hit)
```

That will return true for a bullet_hit value of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9.

Comment: ...or `5.7` or `Math::PI` or `7/3r`, should `bullet_hit` happen to be set to one of those.

Comment: I wasn't a big fan of this method, but I want to say thank you for responding anyways.